# What does means $x("//*");

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

In the console of DevTools on google.com enters:

```
$x("//*");
```

I receive array.

What does means this syntax?

Is it related to jQuery? And if so, how to understand **"//*"**?

Comment: It's the [google chrome command line API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/command-line/command-line-reference?hl=en#xpath)

Comment: What do you mean, 'how to understand "//*"?'? You're the one who entered it...

Comment: Have you tried finding it out yourself by dumping the variable?

Comment: @nnnnnn I ask about it because somebody showed me this example, but he doesn't explain it.

Comment: @PeeHaa yes I have

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that this is a specific feature of Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome's dev tools give you lots of [functions you can use in the console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/command-line/command-line-reference?hl=en). [`$x`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/command-line/command-line-reference?hl=en#xpath) selects based on an XPath selector. `//*` in [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) means "any element," it will select all of the elements in the document (like the CSS `*` selector).